# ElasticSearch REST - insert JSON string without using class

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

I am looking for an example where we can push below sample JSON string to ElasticSearch without using classes in REST api.

```
{
   "UserID":1,
   "Username": "Test",
   "EmailID": "Test@TestElastic.com"
}
```

We get the input as xml and we convert it to JSON string using NewtonSoft.JSON dll.

I know REST api is strongly typed. But is there any way to insert JSON string to Elastic without uses classes in REST api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [low level client](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/elasticsearch-net/building-requests.html) to pass raw json.

```
var elasticsearchClient = new Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClient(settings);
var elasticsearchResponse = elasticsearchClient.Index("index", "type", "{\"UserID\":1,\"Username\": \"Test\",\"EmailID\": \"Test@TestElastic.com\"}");
```

***UPDATE***

Based on [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html), try this one:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.AppendLine("{ \"index\":  { \"_index\": \"indexname\", \"_type\": \"type\" }}");
sb.AppendLine("{ \"UserID\":1, \"Username\": \"Test\", \"EmailID\": \"Test@TestElastic.com\" }");

sb.AppendLine("{ \"index\":  { \"_index\": \"indexname\", \"_type\": \"type\" }}");
sb.AppendLine("{ \"UserID\":2, \"Username\": \"Test\", \"EmailID\": \"Test@TestElastic.com\" }");

var response = elasticsearchClient.Bulk(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Is there bulk insert method for doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Also the observation is - If we use NEST bulk insert then sometimes we get 'operation has timed out' error but with ElasticSearch.Net we dont get such error.

Thanks again.